# How to download a file in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

I have file object

```
var File = new File(["aa"], "dek_iv");
```

can I download this one using  JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: I would suggest going another route, due to Browser compatibility.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an Example how you can download your file Object.

But this will return nothing since the file size is too small for the system to read.

```js
function downloadFile() {

 var file = new File(["aa"], "dek_iv.txt");
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download =file.name;
    link.href = file;
    link.click();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="downloadFile()">Download File</button>
```

Comment: No problem.
If you got the solution then if you can accept it as answer and give an upvote so that others can easily get the answer if they have the same issue.

Comment: But the file content is coming as html i want to see aa in the file i changed below line now its coming as text
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);

Comment: I can't get you can you please elaborate once?

Comment: downloaded file is giving me html content not original content (aa) and for pdf type i am unable to open

Comment: You need to use some libraries if you want the HTML contents in a PDF file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47989089/create-pdf-from-reactjs/47989135#47989135

Comment: "But this will return nothing since the file size is too small for the system to read." can you expand on this? i can't find any reference to a minimum file size

Answer (score 0):

```js
function downloadFile() {

 var file = new File(["aa"], "dek_iv.txt");
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download =file.name;
    link.href = file;
    link.click();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="downloadFile()">Download File</button>
```

Comment: Please enter a comment in your answer.