# How to get react multiple components to pdf view and save when button click

Tags: reactjs, pdf

My parent component like below it have multiple components inside card tag

```
class DashboardPage extends Component {
        render() {
            const { classes } = this.props;
            return (
                <div>
                  <Card>
                    <ProfileHeader {...this.state}/>
                    <ContentLeft {...this.state}/>
                    <ContentRight {...this.state}/>
                    <ContentLeft1 {...this.state}/>
                    <ContentRight1 {...this.state}/>
                    <ProjectTopic {...this.state}/>
                    <ProjectContent {...this.state}/>
                    <ProjectTopic1 {...this.state}/>
                    <ProjectContent1 {...this.state}/>
                    <ProjectTopic2 {...this.state}/>
                    <ProjectContent2 {...this.state}/>
                  </Card>
              </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

How can I get this as pdf please help me im a newbie

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create pdf from ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47989089/create-pdf-from-reactjs)

Comment: can you help me or not

Comment: :) .. please check the link I have added as duplicate. It contains the tool to create pdf